# How to create new apex class and trigger in salesforce professional edition?

Tags: apex, professional-edition

I have enabled apex in salesforce professional edition but there is no option to create new apex class or trigger.

How can I create this in salesforce professional edition?

Comment: I don't believe you can author apex, only run it from packages. I could be wrong though

Comment: Lol 3 within 1 minute.

Comment: At least we all agree

Comment: @AshishPatil We're all saying the same thing: you cannot deploy Apex Code in Professional Edition. It's simply not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm

You cannot author apex. You can only run apex code that is part of a managed package.

Basically you cannot creat apex in the PE org

Enabling apex allows managed packages to run their apex code in your org

You could created a DE org and do your code there, then package it up and deploy it in you PE org

Answer (score 5):

According to the `ISVforce Guide`, you cannot author your own. You can only run `Apex` code included in a managed package.

> ## [Using Apex in Group and Professional Editions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm)
>
> Your app can contain business logic such as classes, triggers, email services, etc. written in Apex. As a general rule, Apex is not supported in GE/PE, so it will not run in these editions. However, Apex developed as part of an ISV app and included in a managed package can run in GE/PE, even though those editions do not support Apex by default.
>
> You must be an eligible partner with salesforce.com and your app has to pass the security review. The appropriate permissions will automatically be enabled after you pass the security review.
>
> Here are some important considerations for using Apex in GE/PE.
>
> - GE/PE customers can’t create or modify Apex in your app; they can only run the existing Apex.
> - Your Apex code should not depend on features and functionality that exist only in DE, EE, UE, or PXE, or your app will fail to install.
> - Make sure to use REST if you plan to expose an Apex method as a Web service. Apex classes that have been exposed as a SOAP Web service can’t be invoked from an external web app in GE/PE.
> - Using Apex to make Web service callouts is allowed in GE/PE. For instance, if you’re planning to make a Web service callout to an external Web service, as long as the managed package is authorized, these classes will function in GE/PE.

Answer (score 5):

You can't create Apex Classses in Professional Edition, as stated in [Define Apex Classes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_define_package.htm&language=en_US&type=0). You must have at least Enterprise Edition to create code.

> ## Define Apex Classes
>
> Available in: Salesforce Classic
>
> Available in: Performance, Unlimited, Developer, Enterprise, and Database.com Editions